# system calls failing for iomapped memory in linux. 

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

I am mapping some io memory to vmalloced area of in the driver. I am also sharing this area with user processes using flag (`PAGE_SHARED` in ioremap_page_range).

Now I am able to access this shared memory into user space. I can write and read to this memory. However, if I pass this memory as a buffer to the system calls like `recv` or `send` then the calls fails with bad memory (`Memory not mapped into user process`).

However, I am sure my buffer does not have any issues. So, there seems to be some conflict in the way I am sharing memory and error check for system calls.

driver code:

```
shared_buf = __get_vm_area(size, VM_IOREMAP, VMALLOCS_START, VMALLOC_END); 
ioremap_page_range(shared_buf->addr, size, phy_addr_of_io, PAGE_SHARED);
```

After that I do an ioctl call and pass this shared_buf->addr to the user space application.
I write and read by using this addr. Then I do

```
ret = recv(sockfd, shared_buf->area, 0) and I get an error "bad addr".
```

Instead of that if I try

```
ret = recv(sockfd, local_buf, size, 0);  
memcpy(shared_buf->addr, local_buf, size); Then it goes without issues.
```

(Disclaimer: I do use `shared_buf->area` in the threads which has not done IOCTL. However it is the same process.)

Can anyone see a mistake?

Comment: You might want to update this again to give your `recv` call enough arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System calls all validate that the pointer passed in is in the user portion of address space. vmalloc space is not in this user portion; hence, you cannot use it for system calls. More importantly, don't give user processes direct access to memory in the vmalloc address space. That's just asking for trouble. And probably horribly insecure - can other processes access that too? Write [an mmapable file instead](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html#t2).

Comment: @bdolan: I kind of had a hitch that there must be a check to see if the addr lies in the user space. However, I was also wondering why the checking is not done on the supervisor bit in the page table. May be kernel developers dont expect programmers to use kernel buffer. (I know mmap is the rite way to go about it.) I used this horrible method of sharing mem as wanted to check something quickly and came across this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @agent.smith, actually looking up the page in the page table is _slow_. The kernel just checks whether it's in the userspace range, then directly accesses it (even in ring 0 the CPU will honor not-present or write-protect bits). The only exception are some very early model 386 processors, in which the kernel indeed checks the page table - but again, this is quite slow.